# My OKI C8800 is skipping/missing a line of black toner in the same position on every page printed

Tags: windows-7, printing

My OKI C8800 is skipping/missing a line of black toner in the same position on every page printed.

I've installed new toner cartridge (Oki original) to no avail. Cyan, magenta and yellow print perfectly.  I've cleaned the data bar inside the top cover, reinstalled drivers (I'm on Windows 7 32 bit) to no avail.

Any suggestions more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [user's guide](http://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/204027/oki-c8800.html?download) for this printer, it looks like it has a RAM slot.  You may try reseating or replacing that RAM if it's there.  (Manual says it has 256MB of internal memory so try removing it if it's there and printing again).

Look for any firmware upgrades for this model.

If not, the control board or motherboard in the printer may need to be replaced.